# For computational programs, how much RAM is too much?

Tags: memory, ram

For computational programs that will be run by all kinds of people on different CPU's, how much RAM consumption is enough to be considered a "bottleneck"? Is there a standard for RAM consumption?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum for general questions about computing. Questions need to be about a specific problem you actually face in the course of software development.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My problem is whether or not I should spend more time reducing ram consumption, and how to ask for more funding to do so in a way that is not just saying "we need this." I voted to close question anyways. I'll post better later when I'm not so tired.

Comment: Another constraint is that questions shouldn't be matters of opinion. How you weight your priorities between hardware cost and development time is very much a matter of personal choice; it doesn't have a provably correct canonical answer. It's certainly possible for good advice to exist on the topic, but that doesn't mean Stack Overflow is the place for it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for more on the guidelines on when subjective questions are and aren't permissible.

Answer (score 1):

RAM is typically not thought of a bottleneck.  "Bottlenecks" tend to be referring to rates, such as RAM bandwidth or CPU instructions per second.

As for whether a given application uses "too much ram," the answer varies *enormously*, across the entire range of possible RAM sizes.  "Too much RAM" for a text editor may be kilobytes, while "Too much RAM" for a particle physics simulation might be terabytes.  Too much video memory for a 3d game would be the point where the graphics card has to put some of the data in system memory, rather than dedicated high speed graphics memory.  On the other hand, if your application needs to run on a low end 8-bit micro-controller, using 600 *bytes* may be a deal breaker.

Also, one must consider virtual memory.  For *many* applications, virtual memory is "good enough," and is always in sufficient supply.  These applications often have large quantities of memory which is not accessed all that often.  For other applications, which access memory more evenly, virtual memory is not an acceptable replacement.

There is a limitation that one should consider, which is how much memory can be installed on a motherboard.  If the current state-of-the-art motherboards only have 4GB of memory, requiring more than 4GB is "too much."  However, I cannot put a number on it in this answer.  Stack exchange answers should withstand the test of time, and that number is *constantly* getting larger.

Comment: In [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that are not "about programming as defined in the help center".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the link.  It may help someone who hasn't been around very long.